# Configuration of jest in react application which is ejected from create react app

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, create-react-app

Unable to run test after eject from create react app.

Step1 : Ejected Create react app

Step2 : In package.json we are using webpack  3.6, and react : 16.8.6

Step3: npm jest,npm enxyme, npm enzyme-adapter-react-16, npm enzyme-react-intl and  inside script:{ test: jest },

step4: npm test

"scripts": {
      "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
  "jest": "^24.8.0",
  "enzyme": "^3.10.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.14.0",
    "enzyme-react-intl": "^2.0.4",
}

Expected React component with intl test case should be pass
Actual :
 *tests*/components/MapControls/SearchLocation.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token

This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

Here's what you can do:
 • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
 • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
 • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

Details:

SyntaxError: C:\Users\admin\Documents\UGVCS-Project\New FE checkout\frontend\app\_tests_\components\MapControls\SearchLocation.test.js: Unexpected token (12:37)

  10 |
  11 | test('submit co-ordinates and test null check', () =>{
> 12 |   const searchComp = shallowWithIntl(<SearchLocation  />);
     |                                      ^
```

Comment: Step 3 is installing packages? `npm i <package_name>`

Comment: yes there is no issue to install packages.